# Writing an Rspec instance variable test

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, tdd

I am trying to test if an instance variable saves input from user but I cant figure out how. I expect the test to pass but it fails and outputs `expected "joe" got: ""` to the terminal. Here is the method, I want to test:

```
def get_names
    while Player.players < 2
      while name.length <= 2
        puts 'Each player must choose a name'
        print 'Enter a name: '
        @name = gets.chomp
      end

      unless name == ''
        @player1 == '' ? @player1 = Player.new(name) : @player2 = Player.new(name)
        name = ''
        puts 'Name have been saved successfully'
      end
    end
  end
```

And here is the rspec test suite:

```
describe Game do
  subject(:game_names) { described_class.new }

  describe '#get_names' do
    context 'when a user inputs name' do
      it 'saves in name instance variable' do
        allow(game_names).to receive(:gets).and_return('joe')
        name = game_names.instance_variable_get(:@name)

        expect(name).to eq 'joe'

        game_names.get_names
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I gave tried mocking and stubbing the class, the method and the variable, but I can't get it to work. This is my first time writing tests.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "can't get it to work". Does the test fail? Do you get an error?

Comment: The test fails and outputs to the terminal: ```expected "joe" got: ""``` yet I expected it to pass

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what the rest of your `Game` and `Player` classes look like. I would say that you may have an execution order problem in your tests. I am basing the following on the assumption that you might not have a `@name` instance variable in your `initialize` method.

So in your tests, you're stubbing the call to `gets` and returning `'joe'` which is cool and exactly what you want. But the next line after that goes and gets the instance variable `@name` which doesn't exist in the class at that moment because the method which sets that instance variable up hasn't been called yet. And undeclared instance variables will always hold the value, `nil`.

So you're essentially comparing `nil` to `'joe'` which will never pass.

What you want to do is move `game_names.get_names` under the `allow` followed by the `instance_variable_get` line, and lastly the `expect` assertion.

```rb
describe Game do
  subject(:game_names) { described_class.new }

  describe '#get_names' do
    context 'when a user inputs name' do
      it 'saves in name instance variable' do
        allow(game_names).to receive(:gets).and_return('joe')
        game_names.get_names

        name = game_names.instance_variable_get(:@name)
        expect(name).to eq 'joe'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The @name is in the initialize method but and can ```game_names.get_names``` be moved anywhere in the test?

Comment: What value does `@name` in the `initialize` hold? And I wouldn't say that `game_names.get_names` can be moved anywhere, it really depends.

Comment: Empty string ```@name = '' ```

Comment: Then I would assume the test fails with something like `expected "joe" got: ""` right? The explanation I provided above still holds true. `game_names.get_names` is what is setting up the `@name` that you want to use for comparison and therefore that method needs to be called before trying to retrieve that instance variable. With the changes I suggested, does the test pass or still fail?

Comment: It still getting ```""```

Comment: The test is still failing

Comment: Then I will ask you to update your question with more context. This would include more of the `Game` class and possibly the `Player` class as well to really get a better understanding of what is going on. You might also want to include the error/output you are getting from the failing test.

Answer (score 0):

The bug was in the `name` assignment to empty string after saving input, so I commented it out and the test passed.